# Set Focus on FlowPane in Javafx

Tags: javafx

i tried

```
public void ChangeFocus(Button browse, final FlowPane mFlowPane)
{
    browse.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

         @Override
         public void handle(KeyEvent event)
         {
             if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB)
             {
                System.out.println("TAB pressed");
                mFlowPane.requestFocus();
                event.consume(); // do nothing
         }
       }
     });

}
```

in above code i set one ImageView inside Flowpane but when i press TAB button on my browse button i can't get focus on imageview how can i solve it?

Answer (score 2):

FlowPane is not focustraversable by default. Call mFlowPane.setFocusTraversable(true) to make it part of the traverse story

Answer (score 2):

some more detail to solve it. instead of focusing the flowpane you need to set the focus on whats in the flowpane, for example a textfield:

```
flowPane.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
{
   public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
   {
         textfield.requestFocus();
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks - this saved my day :-). if you answer this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320018/javafx-key-press-not-captured you will get accepted.